# Is iframe equivalent to window?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to understand a hierarchical picture of `window`, `document` and `iframe`.

So, `window` is simply the browser's window and `document` is where the DOM exists. The `document` is loaded in `window`.

Is creating an `iframe` much like creating a dialog (`window.openDialog()`) (which is nothing but a window)?

Both have a content document and parent window.

Comment: if it helps, an iframe is a nested window, whereas a dialog is a dedicated window. both can have relationships (like a parent) though iframe is based on hierarchy, and a dialog is based on what called it (window.open)

Comment: iframe is an element, and it is .... wait for it .... also an iframe! What you load in that iframe is up to you, but if you load another page, it will have everyting a page normally would have, a contentDocument, tags etc. In other words, an iFrame is not a window, but almost as it contains similar elements.

Comment: ^^ The comments are better than either answer given. +1 to both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very good discussion from WHATWG, the founders of HTML5:
[6 Loading Web pages -- HTML: The Living Standard - Edition for Web Developers](http://developers.whatwg.org/browsers.html#browsers)

In summary, but lots more at the actual page:

> A *browsing context* is an environment in which Document objects are presented to the user.
>
> A tab or window in a Web browser typically contains a browsing context, as does an iframe.

and

> Certain elements (for example, iframe elements) can instantiate further browsing contexts. These are called *nested browsing contexts*.

---

And, if you want to know more about WHATWG:
[FAQ - WHATWG Wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ)